# java map getting incompatible types with child class of an abstract class

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a map like this

```
Map<String, Class<abstractClass>> map = HashMap<String, Class<abstractClass>>();
```

For its input, I tried

```
map.put("exampleString", childClass.class);
```

But this doesn't work, the IDE says wrong 2nd argument type.

```
Found: java.lang.Class<childClass>, required java.lang.Class<abstractClass>
```

Even though there's an inheritance relationship between them.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated: please follow Java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a generic wildcard:

```
Class<? extends abstractClass>
```

This is because generic parameters by default are invariant. You could only put `abstractClass.class` in the map before the change.

By adding `<? extends abstractClass>`, you are making the generic parameter contravariant. In other situations, you can change `extends` to `super` to achieve covariance. There is an acronym for remembering when to use `extends` and when to use `super`, called [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super).

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the childClass.class does not extend / implement the abstract class.

Please show the childClass signature.

Comment: public class childClass extends abstractClass

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't just want:

```
Map<String, abstractClass> map = HashMap<String, abstractClass>();
map.put("exampleString", childClass);
```

?

What you have is you are taking the actual meta signature of the class and putting it into a map, instead of the actual reference to a class

Comment: I want to get the class type I would use with different input of strings, instead of objects. So I think I have to use Class<> and .class..?

Comment: With this implementation, I get expression expected from the childClass part.

Comment: Try this: Class<? extends abstractClass>

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved this problem by changing

```
Class<abstractClass>
```

into

```
Class<? extends abstractClass>
```